# Mysql Query Error 1111 - Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql

```
 SELECT
     count( * ) 
 FROM
    `tp_2018-01` 
 WHERE
     SUBSTRING( scan_date, 1, 10 ) BETWEEN MIN( CAST( SUBSTRING( scan_date, 1, 10 ) AS DATE ) ) 
     AND MAX( CAST( SUBSTRING( scan_date, 1, 10 ) AS DATE ) ) 
     AND nip = '1060001'
```

**and return an error like this**

```
 > 1111 - Invalid use of group function
 > Time: 0,018s
```

this is my table structure

```
 _____________________________
 | id | scan_date | sn | nip | 
 -----------------------------
```

I'm just stuck with this problem.

Comment: You're using aggregate functions in your query. Add a `GROUP BY` clause at the end.

Comment: @RacilHilan, adding group by nip?

Comment: You need to tell us the columns of your table so we can help you. Edit your question and add the table structure.

Comment: @RacilHilan, I've already edit the table structure

Comment: What is the point of the condition `scan_date BETWEEN MIN(scan_date) AND MAX(scan_date)`? Assuming we can use such a condition (we can't), it will always be true, so we'll get the same results with or without it.